# minimal graphic requirements linux distribution

Tags: linux, graphics-card

I have a graphics card that contains only 64MB of RAM. I want to use it in a Linux machine.

Which modern distribution of Linux uses minimal graphic requirements?

Comment: The question is probably better suited for http://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Do you want to use Linux on the command line, or with a GUI?

Answer (score 0):

You can always go cli only. Failing which, most linux distributions DO degrade gracefully with lesser graphics cards. If you want a pre-built ubuntu linux base, that's likely to work, i'd suggest [trinity](http://trinity.pearsoncomputing.net/) [fluxbuntu](http://fluxbuntu.org/) or [wattos](http://www.planetwatt.com/).

Else start with a basic linux install, install X and maybe openbox or fluxbox, and use that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure, and it will depend on other factors like RAM as well. But my expectation is it should work fairly decently, as long as you turn off fancy effects like transparency (and of course stuff like 3-D desktops and such).

What you could do to find out is get a live CD, boot from that (without installing anything on your hard disk) and decide whether the GUI responsitivity is good enough for you. (A live CD system will naturally be much slower when booting, starting applications and so on. But you should be able to get an impression of how the GUI works if you ignore those.)

[Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/) for example comes with a CD/DVD that can be used as a live system. Download [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/download)

Here is a list of lightweight live systems (Note that not all of them come with a GUI): https://superuser.com/questions/121946/lightweight-live-linux-image